# The same local profile for domain users on server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, user-profiles, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

We have a Security Group in AD: ACL_SRV1_USERS. It contains domain accounts USR1, USR2 and USR3.
I need to setup a same local profile for this users/Security Group on member server SRV1.
They needs the same Documents, Desktop icons, ... etc.
Something like "write/save Mandatory profile" :-)
Preferably using a GPO. Is it possible? Could you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (natively) have the same user name locally as on the domain. It would be very confusing if you were to try. That name is also cached locally, so that a laptop user can use it away from the domain.

A much better approach would be to enable Offline Documents.  This is a standard approach for Servers.

Today, in lockdown, and the user may have issues with connection, set up a neutral local folder and the move / sync the documents later.

Likewise (given additional information), each Domain User is unique from all other users. One domain user cannot have two user profiles attached to it.  I do have users with two user names and two different profiles. Administrators may do this to have an Admin User and a Regular User. We do see this. But the profiles are separate an User Folders are also separate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, but I'm a little confused. I probably misrepresented the situation and the question.

My idea is to create a local profile on SRV1, eg C:\Users\Profile_for_ACL_Users. And using a GPO or editing the registry, I set so that when user USR1 or USR2 or USR3 logs on SRV1, it is loaded / redirected to the local profile C:\Users\Profile_for_ACL_Users.

So USR1 logs on SRV1, creates a new document, changes wallpaper, and adds a new icon to it. Then USR1 log out.
Then USR2 logs on SRV1 and sees a new document, a new wallpaper, and a new desktop icon. Etc.

Comment: I have not seen that in years of server work.  A user with a Domain Profile cannot have two independent profiles under one user name. Each user is unique and each profile is attached to just one user. It has been like this in all my consulting years with servers. I added a bit to my answer.